# Function is trying to convert to boolean somewhere

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, dropbox

I have a function in Winforms VB.Net and when I call this function I keep getting an exception saying I can't convert a String to Boolean. However, I can't see where it is trying to convert anything to a Boolean. Code is below

```
Public Async Function UploadArrayToDropbox(client As DropboxClient, folder As String, fileName As String, fileArray As ArrayList) As Task
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream

    Using r As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(stream)
        For i As Integer = 0 To fileArray.Count - 1
            r.WriteLine(fileArray(i).ToString)
        Next
        r.Flush()
        stream.Position = 0

        Using rd As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)

            Dim response = Await client.Files.UploadAsync(Convert.ToString(folder & Convert.ToString("/")) & fileName, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, rd.ReadToEnd)
            rd.Close()
        End Using
        r.Close()
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: Please use debugger to step through code and report where this occurrs.

Comment: Turn **Option Strict On**. This may help with debugging.

Comment: The error keeps throwing on the line
`Dim response = Await client.Files.UploadAsync(Convert.ToString(folder & Convert.ToString("/")) & fileName, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, rd.ReadToEnd)`

Comment: Do you have some sort of top-level exception handler?  If not, when you run under the debugger, it should break at the location where the invalid cast occurs, and then you can inspect the variables on the line to see which one is the boolean.

If you do have a top-level exception handler, then you can still make the debugger break when the exception is thrown.  Go to the Debug menu in Visual Studio, select "Exceptions...", and check "Thrown" for an exceptions where you want to break when it throws (rather than when it's unhandled).  I commonly break when any CLR exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim response = Await client.Files.UploadAsync(Convert.ToString(folder & Convert.ToString("/")) & fileName, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, rd.ReadToEnd)
```

Should be

```
Dim response = Await client.Files.UploadAsync(Convert.ToString(folder & Convert.ToString("/")) & fileName, WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance, body:=rd)
```

From Maurice ;)